# Problem: Visitors will not like a website with no content

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is a general questions regarding building a website with user generated content. A new website will start with no content, then visitors to the site will not want to visit it again because there is no content for them to view.

For example, a review site like Yelp has no reviews will not have return visitors! How do you solve this?

Comment: Might be better asked/answered on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It's true.  You might have noticed my new site, "about:blank".

Comment: This will be off-topic on webapps.SE as well. Not sure about Webmasters.SE

Comment: Or on [answers.onstartups.com](http://answers.onstartups.com/) as this concerns many startups.

Comment: All the options are available: write some yourself (because you would be building a site for a subject dear to your heart), have friends writing some more, buy some initial contents (or reuse freely available contents), pay some people to write some...

Comment: But as such, it's a vague, and irrelevant question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to offer some reason to be there besides the reviews or whatever user-generated content you're trying to integrate into the site. Yelp is a site that searches for restaurants and lists them by type and location, that is the main service which it provides. Offer the user-generated content as a secondary reason to come, then when the user-generated content starts to come in, slowly incorporate it more and more until it becomes the core of the site.

People will only visit your site if they get something out of it, even if it is something as simple as displaying their input in an interesting way.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is off topic I think on every site on the network right now, but for what it's worth, the approach this very site (and the Q&A network that came out of it) took was that of a closed beta - accessible only to a select circle of people -  that would seed the site with content.

See e.g. [Area 51: Asking the First Questions](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/area51/page/3/)

The [Stack Overflow blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/) has many references to avoiding building "Ghost Towns". They're not the only voice on the subject, but they have obviously been very successful with this approach.